# Gradle zip packaging: copy Jar file from repository

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have to copy a jar from the repository (say local) in my ZIP packaging. I understand that we can define compile/runtime in dependencies. However, I could not use it them in ZIP.

I'm able to copy the jar file by specifying the path in my filesystem. However, I don't know how to do it from repository.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
task createZipFile (type: Zip, dependsOn: [...]) {

    baseName 'xyz'

    from(fileTree("src/main"), {
        include "prjName/css/**"
        include "prjName/images/**"
        include "prjName/javascript/**"
        include "prjName/WEB-INF/**"
        exclude "prjName/WEB-INF/web.xml"
    })

    from file("<Absolute-path-to-jar-file-in-my-filesystem>") //this works
    // how to copy the same jar file from repository ??
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dependencies are in the runtime configuration ie:

```
runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.2'
```

you can do:

```
task createZipFile( type: Zip, dependsOn: [...] ) {
    baseName 'xyz'
    from fileTree("src/main"), {
        include "prjName/css/**"
        include "prjName/images/**"
        include "prjName/javascript/**"
        include "prjName/WEB-INF/**"
        exclude "prjName/WEB-INF/web.xml"
    }

    from configurations.runtime.files { it.name == 'slf4j-log4j12' }
}
```

To add all jars downloaded for the dependency with the name `slf4j-log4j12`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm looking for something similar. What if I want to copy multiple jars ? I add 'OR' condition ?

Comment: @Chris That will copy all jar dependencies for `'slf4j-log4j12'` if you want to add more, I'd probably add more `from` lines to catch those in turn (or you could farm this out to a method that takes a list of names and `collects` the results into a list of files, so you'd call something like `from depFinder( 'slf4j-log4j12', 'something-else' )`

Comment: well.. my situation is little different here. I want only the jars I specify. I don't want their dependencies. I just checked that it is copying all the dependencies

Comment: @Chris Ahhh, ok...  Can you give me an example dependency?

Comment: Sure. When I say it.name == "httpclient", it is copying commons-codec-1.4.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, httpclient-4.1.2.jar, httpcore-4.1.2.jar. But I really want is httpclient-4.1.2.jar. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @Chris I ***believe*** that the main jar is always the first in the returned list (and the dependency jars follow), so you should be able to do: `configurations.runtime.files { dep -> dep.name == 'httpclient' }.collect()[0]`

Comment: Awesome !! Thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

To specify a specific jar without its dependencies, qualify it with "@jar". E.g.
"commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.6@jar"
For an example that explains how to reference a set of jars using a custom configuration, see [Download some dependencies and copy them to a local folder](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/download-some-dependencies-and-copy-them-to-a-local-folder/6246)